# Jquery Validate no funciona

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con MVC ASP.NET, la aplicación lleva un formulario para que el usuario se registre y cree una cuenta, el formulario lo estoy validando con JQuery Validate pero no funcionan las validaciones.... Este es el código...

```
    <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-group" id="FormUsuario">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <br />
        <label>Primer apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellido_1" id="Apellido_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" />
        <br />
        <label>Segundo apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellido_2" id="Apellido_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" />
        <br />
        <label>Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" name="E_mail" id="E_mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" />
        <br />
        <label>Teléfono</label>
        <input type="text" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" />
        <br />
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="Contrasenna" id="Contrasenna" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" />
        <br />
        <label>Confirmar contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="txtContrasennaConf" id="txtContrasennaConf" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña" />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnCrearCuenta" id="btnCrearCuenta" value="Crear Cuenta">Crear cuenta</button>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </form>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate();
        EstableceValidaciones();
    });

    function EstableceValidaciones() {
        $("#FormUsuario").validate({
            rules: {
                Nombre: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                Apellido_1: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                Apellido_2: {
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                E_mail: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    email: true
                },
                Telefono: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    digits: true
                },
                Contrasenna: {
                    required: true,
                },
                txtContrasennaConf: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo:"Contrasenna"
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate() {
        $.extend($.validator.messages, {
            maxlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese {0} o menos caracteres"),
            minlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese al menos {0} caracteres"),
            required: $.validator.format("Valor Requerido"),
            url: "Debe ingresar una dirección web válida",
            rangelength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres de longitud"),
            range: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1}"),
            max: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor menor o igual a: {0}"),
            min: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor mayor o igual a: {0}"),
            number: "Favor ingrese un número válido",
            digits: "Favor ingrese solo números",
            email: "Favor ingrese una dirección de correo electrónico válida",
            accept: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            extension: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            require_from_group: $.validator.format("Ingrese al menos uno de estos valores"),
            equalTo: $.validator.format("Los contraseñas no coinciden")

        });
    }
</script>
```

Como ven estoy usando la versión 3.4.1, ya lo he probado con diferentes proyectos y me pasa lo mismo no me valida... A lo que tengo entendido el parámetro que recibe la función .validate es el id del formulario y las rules las van con el name...
Espero que me puedan ayudar...Muchas gracias,saludos!

Comment: Se ve que version de jquery estás probando, pero no qué versión de jquery.validate, ¿cuál es?

Comment: La versión que estoy usando es la v1.17.0....

Comment: Quizás sea la versión, como puedes ver en mi respuesta, con la 1.19.2 funciona... o es que no te has explicado bien en qué _no funciona_...]

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta jachguate, ejecute el código atreves del snippet y las validaciones funcionan, pero cuando lo pruebo en el navegador y envío el formulario vació para probar que las validaciones que hice con jquery funcionan, no aparece nada comparado a como sale en el ejemplo que ejecute por acá.....

Comment: Viendo los datos que salen en la pantalla de salida de Visual Studio al momento de realizar la prueba en el navegador encontré este mensaje:

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
    at EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate (https://localhost:44355/Usuario/IngresaUsuario:112:24)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44355/Usuario/IngresaUsuario:73:3)
    at mightThrow (https://localhost:44355/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js:3766:29)
    at process (https://localhost:44355/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js:3834:12) undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Comment: Creo que debieras, entonces, preparar una nueva pregunta, con el formulario más simple e incluir la información pertinente de cómo estás usándolo desde Visual Studio, pues evidentemente es un problema que tiene que ver con cómo lo usas desde allí. Un [mcve] que alguien que tenga experiencia usándolo desde ese entorno pueda usar para reproducir tu problema y ayudarte a resolverlo sería lo ideal.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda jachguate!!! Voy a hacer eso mismo y voy a ver como me va!!!!

Answer (score 1):

No sé a que le llamas "no validar", pero este es básicamente tu mismo código con `jquery` 3.4.1 y `jquery.validate` 1.19.2.

En mi opinión, si que valida. Puedes probarlo aquí mismo dando clic al botón "Ejecutar", al final del *snippet*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
        EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate();
        EstableceValidaciones();
    });

    function EstableceValidaciones() {
        $("#FormUsuario").validate({
            rules: {
                Nombre: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                Apellido_1: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                Apellido_2: {
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                E_mail: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    email: true
                },
                Telefono: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    digits: true
                },
                Contrasenna: {
                    required: true,
                },
                txtContrasennaConf: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo:"Contrasenna"
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate() {
        $.extend($.validator.messages, {
            maxlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese {0} o menos caracteres"),
            minlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese al menos {0} caracteres"),
            required: $.validator.format("Valor Requerido"),
            url: "Debe ingresar una dirección web válida",
            rangelength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres de longitud"),
            range: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1}"),
            max: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor menor o igual a: {0}"),
            min: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor mayor o igual a: {0}"),
            number: "Favor ingrese un número válido",
            digits: "Favor ingrese solo números",
            email: "Favor ingrese una dirección de correo electrónico válida",
            accept: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            extension: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            require_from_group: $.validator.format("Ingrese al menos uno de estos valores"),
            equalTo: $.validator.format("Los contraseñas no coinciden")

        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-group" id="FormUsuario">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <br />
        <label>Primer apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellido_1" id="Apellido_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" />
        <br />
        <label>Segundo apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellido_2" id="Apellido_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" />
        <br />
        <label>Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" name="E_mail" id="E_mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" />
        <br />
        <label>Teléfono</label>
        <input type="text" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" />
        <br />
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="Contrasenna" id="Contrasenna" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" />
        <br />
        <label>Confirmar contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="txtContrasennaConf" id="txtContrasennaConf" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña" />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnCrearCuenta" id="btnCrearCuenta" value="Crear Cuenta">Crear cuenta</button>
    </form>
</div>
```